# Unable to authorise using jsch private key

Tags: java, macos, jsch

I am trying to connect to a local ssh for testing purposes.

I am trying to login using ssh keys with jsch.

This is what I am putting in config:

config.put(STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECK, strictHostKeyCheckValue); // no
config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");

The keys are valid and I am passing in the correct path to them.

The sever is running in background.
But I am not able to connect to it.
The error is “Auth failed”.
Can anyone suggest where should I look further.

I am working on macos.

Comment: is there any passphrase for the key if yes are you passing the passphrase? Also add the sample code.

Comment: no passphrase is used.

Comment: sadly jsch error message is not that verbose whats wrong. I recommend using jsch fork and also have a look at https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/wiki/Jsch-Configuration Dont do strictHostChecking no, that is bad and insecure practise

Comment: yes that is for testing purpose only.

Comment: added code for same.

Comment: Is your public key in authorized_keys on the server? If not, you won't be able to use your private key

Comment: Incidentally, STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECK is unrelated to your problem. That is about mapping hosts to their key fingerprints so that host spoofing can be detected.

Comment: okay, how do I authurize it ? The thing is I am connecting to local computer. I am using intellij in same computer and I am giving it the path to the ssh directory.  So is not it authorized automatically ? Strict host key checking is when you want your client to connect to any server whose key is not hosted on client --- correct me if I am wrong, or maybe if possible provide any source to learn it, I just googled it. --- it can be related incase the "auth fails" is due to since host key of server (localhost) is not known to client (jsch). Correct me If I am wrong. @g00se

Comment: I just verifed public key is in known hosts file in ssh directory.

Comment: In my ssh directory, there is no authorized_keys file there, It has known_hosts file. Moreover if I am not wrong you are talking about id_rsa which is private key. I am sure private key is not there. So you want me to put private key there, I checked for public key which is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242760/discussion-between-g00se-and-abhinav-batta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used ssh where the client and server are the same host, but I just tried. The server STILL uses ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to look for the public key. IS it there? Make sure with cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys. That at least is what my public key file is. Yours might be different.

Comment: yes, the public key needed to be added to server.